# SwiftUI - State without an initial value

Tags: swiftui, state, default

I have a state declared in my view

```
@State var selected: Bool = false
@State var selectedPerson: Person
```

When a "Person" is selected from a view there is a callback that sets the "selected" state to true, and sets the person that is selected:

```
MapView(viewModel: MapViewModel(people: viewModel.people)) { value in
     selectedPerson = viewModel.getPersonWith(name: value.title)
     selected = true
}
```

When all of this is set, it triggers a NavigationLink like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: PersonDetailsView(viewModel: PersonViewModel(person: selectedPerson)), isActive: self.$selected) {
      EmptyView()
}.hidden()
```

Everything works fine, but I have to set a default value to the "selectedPerson" state before the struct is initialized, even tho there is no person selected. Is there a way to bypass this, without giving the "selectedPerson" state a default "dummy" value.
Thanks :)

Comment: Just make it an optional `@State var selectedPerson: Person?` and use the other NavigationLink initialiser that takes binding to an optional value. You can also remove. selected completely

Comment: @LuLuGaGa Can you give me an example please, the app crashed because it receives a nil value from the optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make initial state optional, like

```
@State var selectedPerson: Person?
```

but as well you have to handle this optional in all places that use it, like

```
if nil != selectedPerson {
   NavigationLink(destination: 
      PersonDetailsView(viewModel: PersonViewModel(person: selectedPerson!)), // << !!
                              isActive: self.$selected) {
      EmptyView()
   }.hidden()
}
```